# apns push notifications is not working with production certificate

Tags: iphone, push-notification

I've enabled push notifications for my App ID and checked in development that is fine, but in production i am not getting notifications.

I used the [following code](http://rajendradhanora.blogspot.in/2011/07/iphone-push-notification-using-netc.html) in my server side.

Here are the steps I have followed when switching from production to development:

1. used the production SSL certificate key
2. changed the sandbox to false in above blog

I cross checked my  distribution  provisioning profile which contains key  aps-environment and production mode

Is there any thing still I need to change, how can I cross check where I am going wrong?

I already downloaded my app from iTunes portal, but I did keep  my .p12 file in my project while archiving, is it necessary?

Comment: Which part doesn't work? The registration to APNS (do you get a production device token?) or sending the notifications (which would indicate a problem in the server side)?

Comment: actually iam using development device token, bun now as iam searching the device token is different for both production and development may i know how its look like, my database has somany devvicetoken how to know my iphone production device token

Comment: I don't now whether it helps on you but we are using it for the generic push notifications: http://www.pushwoosh.com. it was 30 mins to set up everything, and it is free.

Comment: i got somany device token now i want to test notifications,how to know my iphone device token, other wise my clients will also recceive notifications na

Comment: @siva. Try to find device toke log in you local server. In SQL server you will find logs. Also make web service and send device token using web service to server.

Answer (score 1):

Device tokens are different for development and production environment. Production device tokens are invalid in development environment and vica versa. You should have maintained different databased for the production tokens and development tokens. Now that you have them mixed it's a bit tricky to tell them apart.

You can find out which device token are invalid in the production environment (which means they are probably development tokens) by sending notifications for all your device tokens. After each send you should try to read an error response from Apple. Error response 8 means invalid device token. You should use a long timeout for that read (since it sometimes takes time to get the error response from Apple).

Comment: that is not my actual problem i have lots of device tokens.all of them are production only,now i have a device which contains my app ,and my app is downloaded by other members also,so i have my device token, all other device token, how can i know my device token

Comment: @siva You can run your app from xcode and check the device token in the debugger (put a breakpoint in the method that returns the device token).

Comment: then i am getting development device token not productionn device token

Comment: @siva If you are getting a development device token, it means that your app was build with a development provisioning profile. You should build it with a production provisioning profile.

Comment: if i use distribution provisioning profile in debug place iam getting error as invalid provisioning profile